# Getting form data from ng-included fields without using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form where the contents are loaded by `ng-include`:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <div ng-include="currentForm"></div>
</form>
```

The `ng-include`d fields will not have any `ng-model`s associated with them, for example:

```
<input type="number" name="age" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

How can I access the form data from within the `submitForm` function?

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
  // access form variables here
}
```

I've tried examining `this` within `submitForm` but that just spits out the `ChildScope` object.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-model?

Comment: @jedanput Because these fields are brought in dynamically from a source which isn't using angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the easy ugly way, or you could do this the elegant pompous way:

The easy way is to pass the `$event` object to the submit form, and extract the form fields from there:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm($event)">
   <input name="bar">
</form>
```

And handle this in the controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(event){
   var bar = event.currentTarget.bar.value;
}
```

The more elegant way is to define a directive that adds `ng-model` to input elements in the included form and re-compiles it. Suppose it is used like below, and it publishes the form ng-models onto `fooModel` on the scope:

```
<div ng-include="'form.html'" included-form-model="fooModel"></div>
```

Theoretically, it could look like so (the example assumes full jQuery is included, for simplicity of illustration, and all form elements have `name` attribute defined):

```
.directive("includedFormModel", function($compile){
  return {
    require: "?ngInclude",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngInclude){
      if (!ngInclude) return;

      var model = attrs.includedFormModel; // the name under which to publish
      scope.$parent[model] = {};

      var unwatch = scope.$on("$includeContentLoaded", function(){
        inputElements = element.find(":input").each(function(idx, elem){
           elem.setAttribute("ng-model", model + "." + elem.name);
        });
        $compile(inputElements)(scope);
      });

      scope.$on("$destroy", function(){ unwatch(); });
    }
  }
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBWeKL6AFGJo5jcDXsbA?p=preview)

Comment: Amazing. Really pragmatic approach. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. There was actually a typo. It's supposed to be `scope.$on`, not `scope.$watch - fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is prefered to use ng-model on the element.But you can access it by jquery

```
$( "input[name='age']")
```